# App supporting both iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios

I need my app to run on both `iOS6` and `iOS7`. Do I have to put a key for that in my `info.plist` file?? Or is there any other way to provide this information?

Comment: Do a search on "Deployment Target".

Comment: ok.. i will read the details and get back to you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set *Deployment Target* to the earliest release of iOS you want to support:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the following warning: "iOS deployment target '7.0' for architecture 'armv7s' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '6.1.99' for the iOS 6.1 SDK."

Comment: Hey i just got rid of the warning.. i didn't change the deployment target in my project settings, and i did that only in target settings.. once i did that for project settings, the problem went away..

Comment: This is what i had to do??? right?? change the "deployment target" in both "project settings" and "target settings"??

Answer (score 0):

Just set **deployment target as 6.0** which means support for ios6+..

Comment: I didn't change the deployment target in my project settings, and i did that only in target settings.. so i was getting a warning.. once i did that for project settings, the problem went away..
This is what i had to do??? right?? change the "deployment target" in both "project settings" and "target settings"??

Comment: Yes, you have to change in both. But normally, while change in project  -> Target -> General -> deployment target, will also change in both.